# Bootstrap modal on page load is not happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a login/signup modal it is working fine,but i need to open the modal when the page loads
I have taken the code from [here](https://codyhouse.co/demo/login-signup-modal-window/index.html)

I have changed my code like this and i need to open the reset password modal when the page loads.

Modal Code

```
 <div id="cd-reset"> 
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 Mask2" align="center">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">

              </div>           
            </div>
          </div> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on('load',function(){
            $('#cd-reset').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
```

but its not working. when I load the page it does not display the modal/popup
can anyone suggest me how to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give us a live link or your code snippet, because we can't help you with you provided details!

Comment: you modal div should have model class otherwise it will not work. '<div id="cd-reset" class="modal fade">'

Comment: here is working code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPDNN2ZIUML7

Comment: @ weBBer The link is this https://codyhouse.co/gem/loginsignup-modal-window/  would you suggest how to do

Comment: @ danish farhaj  but am using this link https://codyhouse.co/gem/loginsignup-modal-window/

Comment: What does this have to do with bootstrap modal. Codyhouse is using a custom modal?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the bootstrap modals need certain classes to give you the feel. You need to use the exact classes to get the modal pop-up. Also, in your code there is no content (text) and thus why you're not seeing anything.
Code should look like below.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the code.but cant we use without modal .i have referred this https://codepen.io/codyhouse/pen/pIrbg. pls give me suggestion